# Quicktime video recording doesn't work properly

Tags: macos, quicktime

This has happened on two occasions now where I'd make a 30minute video using quicktime's video recording and it only records like the first minute and the last minute, and the middle 28 minutes gets stuck on the first minute's frame. The sound is recorded properly, but the video is not.

Can someone advise how to fix this situation?

Is there another software for recording (with the macbook camera, not screen recording) that works better?

I'm using macOS 12.4. MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2019). 663 GB disk space remaining. For resolution, it seems there are 2 options, "high" and "maximum". seems it defaults to "high" so that's probably what I used in the past

Comment: What Mac, what OS, what camera, how much drive space do you have left, what resolution are you trying to capture?

Comment: @Tetsujin
12.4. MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2019). 663 GB remaining. For resolution, it seems there are 2 options, "high" and "maximum". seems it defaults to "high" so that's probably what I used in the past